# PHP Syntax validator?

Tags: php

Im just wondering if theres a recommended syntax validator out there anybody can recommend?

Having major issues and cant figure it out...

```
    <?php 
    session_start();
       if (isset ($_SESSION['id'])) {header("location: home.php");} 
       if (array_key_exists("login", $_GET)){$oauth_provider = $_GET['oauth_provider'];
       if ($oauth_provider == 'twitter')
       {
           header("Location: login-twitter.php");
       }  
       else if ($oauth_provider == 'facebook'){
           header("Location: login-facebook.php");
       }
       }
    ?>

 <a href="?login&oauth_provider=twitter">Twitter_Login</a>
 <a href="?login&oauth_provider=facebook">Facebook_Login</a>
```

Comment: If it was a syntax issue the odds are an error would be thrown by the php parser.

Comment: it's also a good idea to layout your code so it's more easily read (with indentation etc), it makes finding unhelpful error message causes more easily done. See this for an example using your provided code example: http://codepad.org/Q4ld9Cc6

Comment: Not an answer to you rquestion, but a possible bug in your script: You should put an exit after the `header`, otherwise the rest of the script wil run too. Doesn't need to be a problem, but might be if you do database stuff in there. Anyway, just a headsup :)

Comment: Off-topic, for Liam: I just commented against your most recent question, but you deleted it in the meantime. This isn't best practice for that very reason - if you want to migrate a question to _Programmers_ then use the 'flag' option and ask the moderator to do it for you. Sorry Sergio was rude to you - one needs tough skin for StackOverflow! `:-(`

Comment: Thanks @halfer I didnt realise the programmers section was for that purpose, He did make sense saying give it a go and see what happens however, thanks again :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`php -l` on the command-line will do a syntax check

[codepad.org](http://codepad.org) is an easy way to test code online.

Your example code does not contain syntax errors: http://codepad.org/0diycu9o

Comment: If one use not IDE, but some light editor like Scite, it is useful to set up compile/build command to something like `php -l %file%` into editor.